# How To Obtain A Reducing Sugar At Home?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, carbohydrates

I'm looking for a reducing sugar such as glucose or maltose (any reducing sugar will do) for some home chemistry experiments. Is there a readily available reducing sugar that I might source without contacting a chemical company? A simple "synthesis" of glucose from sucrose would work as well.

Comment: Glucose can be found in drug stores and does not require a recipe in some countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As permeakra mentions, glucose can be purchased pretty easily. It might be labeled as "[dextrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrose)".

Another commonly available is [maltose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose) (or malt sugar).

[Sucrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucrose) (or table sugar) is not a reducing sugar, but one of its constituents (glucose) is. Glucose can be made from sucrose by heating with a little bit of acid to make [invert sugar syrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invert_sugar). Invert sugar is approximately a 1:1 ratio of glucose to fructose, and only the glucose in this mixture is reducing. An example procedure can be found here:[How does adding lemon juice to sugar make better caramel?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/555/how-does-adding-lemon-juice-to-sugar-make-better-caramel/556#556). [Honey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey) is a naturally occurring invert sugar.